# Retrieve privileges using security role rather than using system user

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, console-application

Here is my code:

```
RetrievePrincipalAccessRequest request = new RetrievePrincipalAccessRequest();
request.Principal = new EntityReference("systemuser", new Guid("GUID of system user record."));
// record for which we want to check the access
request.Target = new EntityReference("account", new Guid("GUID of account record."));
try
{
    RetrievePrincipalAccessResponse responce = (RetrievePrincipalAccessResponse)organisationservice.Execute(request);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("error" + ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

It take out "can access| can edit| can read" privilege for system user and **a
security principal can be either user or team** but not a security role, therefore is there any C# code which can retrieve privileges using a security role.

I have Dynamic CRM Online instance.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you want to retrieve all privileges for a security role you can use [RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrieveroleprivilegesrolerequest.aspx) like this:

```
var roleRequest = new RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest { RoleId = new Guid("securityRoleId") };
var roleReponse = service.Execute(roleRequest);
```

Replace `"securityRoleId"` with your `securityrole.Id.ToString()` and `service` with your `organisationservice`.

`roleResponse.RolePrivileges` will contain a long list of privilege IDs which are not very useful on their own. You could get the name of all of these privileges like this:

```
var privilegeQuery = new QueryExpression { EntityName = "privilege", ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true) };

var filter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.Or);

foreach (var p in roleResponse.RolePrivileges)            
    filter.AddCondition("privilegeid", ConditionOperator.Equal, p.PrivilegeId);

privilegeQuery.Criteria = filter;

var privileges = service.RetrieveMultiple(privilegeQuery);
```

Now you will have all columns (attributes) for all privileges for a given security role stored in `privileges`.

---

I think/hope that answers your question. However to go one step further, you could filter your `privileges` by the entity they refer to as well:

```
var contactPrivileges = privileges.Entities.ToList()
            .Where(p => p.GetAttributeValue<string>("name").ToLower()
            .Contains("contact"))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: `foreach (var p in res.RolePrivileges)  `  what **res** indicate here.

Comment: **res** should have been **roleResponse**. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It was assumed you'd replace my placeholders with your own variables. I've edited my answer to state the replacements. Glad you were successful.

Comment: Thanks, It works for me after adding `RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest req = new RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest();req.RoleId = new Guid("securityRoleId");RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleR‌​esponse response = (RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleResponse)organisationservice.Exec‌​ute(req);`and removing `var roleRequest = new RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest { RoleId = new Guid("securityRoleId") };var roleReponse = service.Execute(roleRequest);`

Comment: I want to make your focus on to change `var` with  `RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest` .

Comment: They're equivalent.

Comment: Then Why I am getting this error using your code - **'OrganizationResponse' does not contain a definition for 'RolePrivileges' and no extension method 'RolePrivileges' accepting a first argument of type 'OrganizationResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Answer (score 0):

I have found one another solution:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "role"
};

//Get all Security Roles
EntityCollection Securityroles = organisationservice.RetrieveMultiple(query);
//Get all Privileges
RetrievePrivilegeSetRequest requestp = new RetrievePrivilegeSetRequest();
RetrievePrivilegeSetResponse responsep = (RetrievePrivilegeSetResponse)organisationservice.Execute(requestp);
foreach (Entity securityrole in Securityroles.Entities)
{

    //Get record from RolePrivilege Mapping
    RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest req = new RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest();
    req.RoleId = new Guid(securityrole.Id.ToString());
    RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleResponse response = (RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleResponse)organisationservice.Execute(req);

    foreach (RolePrivilege priv in response.RolePrivileges)
    {
        var privile = responsep.EntityCollection.Entities.Where(a => a.Id == priv.PrivilegeId).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To those who are getting error on Dave Clark code, replace the below code

```
var roleRequest = new RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest { RoleId = new Guid(roleId.ToString()) }; 
var roleReponse = service.Execute(roleRequest);
```

with

```
RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest roleRequest = new RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest { RoleId = new Guid(roleId.ToString()) };
        RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleR‌​esponse roleResponse = (RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleResponse)_service.Execute(roleRequest);
```